# Perl script to make first 8 characters all caps but not the whole file name

Tags: perl, file, rename

What Perl script should I be using to only change the first 8 characters in a file name to all caps instead of the script changing the entire file name to all caps?

Here is how I am setting it up:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

chdir "directory path";
#@files = `ls *mw`;
@files = `ls | grep mw`;
chomp @files;

foreach $oldname (@files) {
  $newname = $oldname;
  $newname =~ s/mw//;
  print "$oldname -> $newname\n";
  rename("$oldname","$newname");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this regex:

```
my $str = 'Hello World!';
$str =~ s/^(.{8})/uc($1)/se; # $str now contains 'HELLO WOrld!'
```

Comment: Here is how I am setting it up#!/usr/bin/perl

chdir "directory path";

#@files = `ls *mw`;
@files = `ls | grep mw`;
chomp @files;

foreach $oldname (@files)
{
 $newname = $oldname;
 $newname =~ s/mw//;

 print "$oldname -> $newname\n";
 rename("$oldname","$newname");
}

Comment: Here is how I am setting it up

#!/usr/bin/perl

chdir "directory path";

$str =~ s/(^.{8})/uc($1)/e;

Do I need to close it off? I am new to perl so I apologize if this is an obvious question.

Comment: After the 'mw'-removing part in the loop, just add `$newname =~ s/(^.{8})/uc($1)/e;`.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

chdir "directory";

foreach my $file(@files) {
    # Change filename to uppercase even if the length is < 8 char
    $FILE =~ s/^.{1,8}/uc$&/e;
    move($file, $FILE);
}
not sure if this is formatted correctly on my side

Comment: From both efficiency and security points of view it is best to avoid an evaluated substitution where possible. Also, your code will set nothing to upper case if the file name is less than eight characters. `s/(^.{1,8})/\U$1/` works fine.

Comment: @Borodin, you're confusing /e with `eval EXPR`. `s///e` is actually more like `do BLOCK`. There's absolutely no security problem with `s///e`. `s///ee`, on other hand, is equivalent to `s//eval/e`, and it is problematic.

Comment: @Borodin, Furthermore, you greatly over estimate the efficiency benefit. Both `s//\U$1/` and `s//uc($1)/e` are compiled when the s/// is compiled (not when it's run), and both call `uc`.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't working. I'm using: #!/usr/bin/perl

chdir "directory path";

foreach $oldname (@files)
{
 $newname =~ s/(^.{1,8})/\U$1/e;

 print "$oldname -> $newname\n";
 rename("$oldname","$newname");
}

Comment: @user1295706 You forgot the line `$newname = $oldname;` before the regex.

Answer (score 4):

The substitution

```
s/^(.{1,8})/\U$1/
```

will set the first eight characters of a string to upper case. The complete program looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

chdir "directory path" or die "Unable to change current directory: $!";

opendir my $dh, '.' or die $!;
my @files = grep -f && /mw/, readdir $dh;

foreach my $file (@files) {
  (my $new = $file) =~ s/mw//;
  $new =~ s/^(.{1,8})/\U$1/s;
  print "$file -> $new\n";
  rename $file, $new;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

chdir'/path/to/directory';
# Find all files that contain 'mw'
my @files = glob("*mw*");

foreach my $file(@files) {
    # skip directories
    next if -d $file;
    # remve 'mw' from the filename
    (my $FILE = $file) =~ s/mw//;
    # Change filename to uppercase even if the length is <= 8 char
    $FILE =~ s/^(.{1,8})/uc $1/se;
    move($file, $FILE);
}
```

As said in the doc for [rename](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html), you'd better use [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) to be platform independent.

Comment: Using `$&` slows down every regex match in your program that doesn't have captures (e.g. `s/mw//`).  Either use `${^MATCH}` (with `/p`) or use a capture. I changed your code to use a capture.

Comment: @ikegami: You're perfectly right, but does it deserve a downvote?

Comment: @M42, No, especially since I fixed it. I did not downvote. Here's an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

## Always check return values of system calls!

When you make any call to OS services, you should **always** check the return value. For example, the Perl documentation for [`chdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) is (with added emphasis)

> **`chdir EXPR`**
>    **`chdir FILEHANDLE`**
>    **`chdir DIRHANDLE`**
>    **`chdir`**
>
> Changes the working directory to *EXPR*, if possible. If *EXPR* is omitted, changes to the directory specified by `$ENV{HOME}`, if set; if not, changes to the directory specified by `$ENV{LOGDIR}`. (Under VMS, the variable `$ENV{SYS$LOGIN}` is also checked, and used if it is set.) If neither is set, `chdir` does nothing. **It returns true on success, false otherwise.** See the example under die.
>
> On systems that support fchdir(2), you may pass a filehandle or directory handle as the argument. On systems that don't support fchdir(2), passing handles raises an exception.

As written in your question, your code discards important information: whether system calls `chdir` and `rename` succeeded or failed.

## Providing useful error messages

An example of a common idiom for checking return values in Perl is

```
chdir $path or die "$0: chdir $path: $!";
```

The error message contains three important bits of information:

- the program emitting the error, [`$0`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%240)
- what it was trying to do, `chdir` in this case
- why it failed, [`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24!)

Also note that `die` also the name of the file and line number where program control was if your error message does not end with newline. When the `chdir` fails, the standard error will resemble

```
./myprogram: chdir: No such file or directory at ./myprogram line 3.
```

Logical or is true when at least one of its arguments is true. The “do something or die” idiom works because if `chdir` above fails, it returns a false value and requires `or` to evaluate the right-hand side and terminates execution with `die`. In the happy case where `chdir` succeeds and returns a true value, there is no need to evaluate the right-hand side because we already have one true argument to logical or.

## Suggested improvements to your code

For what you’re doing, I recommend using [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) to avoid problems in case one of the filenames contains whitespace. Note the [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) test in the code below that’s there to stop a file named `0` (*i.e.*, a single zero character) terminating your loop.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

chdir "directory path" or die "$0: chdir: $!";

opendir $dh, "." or die "$0: opendir: $!";

while (defined($oldname = readdir $dh)) {
  next unless ($newname = $oldname) =~ s/mw//;
  $newname =~ s/^(.{1,8})/\U$1/;
  rename $oldname, $newname or die "$0: rename $oldname, $newname: $!";
}
```

For the `rename` to have any hope, you have to preserve the value of `$oldname`, so right away, the code above copies it to `$newname` and starts changing the copy rather than the original. You will see

```
($new = $old) =~ s/.../.../;  # or /.../
```

in Perl code, so it is also an important idiom to understand.

The [perlop documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) defines handy escape sequences for use in strings and regex substitutions:

> `\l` lowercase next character only
>   `\u` titlecase (not uppercase!) next character only
>     `\L` lowercase all characters till \E seen
>     `\U` uppercase all characters till \E seen
>     `\Q` quote non-word characters till \E
>     `\E` end either case modification or quoted section (whichever was last seen)

The code above grabs the first eight characters (or fewer if `$newname` is shorter in length) and replaces them with their upcased counterparts.

## Example output

See the code in action:

```
$ ls directory\ path/
defmwghijk  mwabc  nochange  qrstuvwxyzmw

$ ./prog

$ ls directory\ path/
ABC  DEFGHIJK  QRSTUVWXyz  nochange
```

Comment: Is there an *answer* in here somewhere?!

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for your feedback. Please suggest how I might make my answer more helpful. OP is self-described as being new to Perl, so I provided additional context.

Comment: It's a tough call deciding how much background information to include. I would say that perhaps the solution (and the demonstration of its effectiveness) should come first followed by the commentary. In this case I think you could usefully add some bold headers as well to demarcate the body of your response.

Answer (score 1):

I figure there's more to your requirements than you're telling us, such as not uppercasing parts of the file extension. Instead of matching the first eight characters, I'll match the first eight *letters*:

```
use v5.14;
use utf8;

chdir "/Users/brian/test/";
my @files = glob( 'mw*' );

foreach my $old (@files) {
    my $new = $old =~ s/\Amw(\pL{1,8})/\U$1/ir;
    print "$old → $new\n";
    }
```

Some other notes:

- You can do the glob directly in Perl. You don't need `ls`.
- It looks like you were stripping off `mv`, so I did that. If that's not what you want, it's easy to change.

Comment: `\pL` will not match filename that contain non-letter.

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of a regular expression to up-case the first eight characters you could use the 4-argument form of [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html).  This offers in situ replacement.

```
my $old = q(abcdefghij);
my $new = $old;
substr( $new, 0, 8, substr( uc($old), 0, 8 ) );
print "$old\n$new\n";

abcdefghij
ABCDEFGHij
```

Use `rename` or `File::Copy::move` (as M42 showed) to perform the actual rename.